# "column doesn't exist" when using a WHERE clause in joined tables

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

A `CreditCard` `belongs_to` a `User`. A `Subscription` also `belong_to` `User`.

I'm trying to query all `CreditCard`s that `belong_to` a `User` where the `Subscription.status` is `"authorized"`

```
select * from credit_cards
join users on users.id = credit_cards.user_id
join subscriptions on users.id = subscriptions.user_id
where subscriptions.status = "authorized"
```

returns `ERROR: column "authorized" does not exist`

where Subscription.status = "authorized" gives me `missing FROM-clause entry for table "subscription"`

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

String literals in SQL are denoted by single quotes (`'`), not double quotes (`"`) like you have in your query:

```sql
select * from credit_cards
join users on users.id = credit_cards.user_id
join subscriptions on users.id = subscriptions.user_id
where subscriptions.status = 'authorized'
-- Here ---------------------^----------^
```